# Use regex to remove after closing parenthesis

Tags: c#, regex

I want to use regex to remove after closing parenthesis. Any help?

Original:

```
CREATE TABLE "EMP" 
   (    "EMPNO" NUMBER(4,0) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "ENAME" VARCHAR2(10), 
    "JOB" VARCHAR2(9), 
    "MGR" NUMBER(4,0), 
    "SAL" NUMBER(7,2), 
    "DEPTNO" NUMBER(2,0)
   ) PCTFREE 10 PCTUSED 40 INITRANS 1 MAXTRANS 255 NOCOMPRESS LOGGING
  STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
  PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1 BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "USERS" 
 ;
```

I want

```
 CREATE TABLE "EMP" 
   (    "EMPNO" NUMBER(4,0) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "ENAME" VARCHAR2(10), 
    "JOB" VARCHAR2(9), 
    "MGR" NUMBER(4,0), 
    "SAL" NUMBER(7,2), 
    "DEPTNO" NUMBER(2,0)
   ) 
 ;
```

Comment: Do you have anything already? Do you know how to use a lookbehind?

Comment: I don't know if there is a clean way with a regexp to check if the closing `)` is really closing the whole thing, but you could do it by counting the opening and closing ones.

Comment: I think `String` methods would be better for your problem rather than the `Regex`.

Comment: what is string method?

Answer (score 1):

you could use something like:

```
Regex.Replace(str, @"\)\s*\)[^;]*", ")\n)");
```

let me know if its working...

Comment: Hi Robin, I have a richtextbox inside winform application and this richtextBox consist of my above text. how can I write C# code to check this? any suggestion?

Comment: +1 that worked for me however I did remove the `;` from the replace block as it seemed to insert an additional `;` into my output.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
string less = Regex.Replace(str, "^([^)]*).*", "$1);");
```